# single-row subquery returns more than one row in oracle in HR schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

```
select employee_id, first_name, job_id, salary 
from employees where salary < ( select SALARY 
                                FROM EMPLOYEES 
                                WHERE JOB_ID='IT_PROG');
```

and I found an error like the following :

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are "many" employees whose `job_id = 'IT_PROG'`. In that case, subquery returns "many rows" and your query results in an error.

It depends on what you want to do in such a case; for example, you might want to return rows for employees whose salary is lower than minimum salary for `IT_PROG`, so that would be

```
SELECT employee_id,
       first_name,
       job_id,
       salary
  FROM employees
 WHERE salary < (SELECT MIN (SALARY)               --> note MIN function here
                   FROM EMPLOYEES
                  WHERE JOB_ID = 'IT_PROG');
```

Comment: Alternatively `where salary < all (select ...)`